# text to column, do not repeat column name

Tags: r

I have a df that looks as follows:

```
id  name                 grade
1   rich, tom, todd,     12
2   chris,mary           9
3   larry                10
```

I run the following code to split text to column:

```
newdf <- within(df, name<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(name), ',', fixed=TRUE))))
```

And here is my output:

```
id  name.X1   name.X2   name.X3    grade
1   rich       tom       todd       12
2   chris      mary      chris      9
3   larry      larry     larry      10
```

The code I have is repeating names(in id 2 & 3), as opposed to putting in blanks or NA.  What I'd like the code to output is the following:

```
  id    name.X1   name.X2   name.X3    grade
  1     rich       tom       todd       12
  2     chris      mary      N/A        9
  3     larry      N/A       N/A        10
```

Or instead of N/A I'd like for the cells to be left blank.  Any idea how I can avoid having it repeat names?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "name", ",")
#   id grade name_1 name_2 name_3
#1:  1    12   rich    tom   todd
#2:  2     9  chris   mary     NA
#3:  3    10  larry     NA     NA
```

---

If we are using `strsplit`, as the `list` elements are of unequal length, it may be better to pad with NAs or else the elements get repeated.  For padding with NA at the end, one option is to get the `length` of each of the `list` element which can be done with `lengths`, take the `max` ('mx') and assign the `length` to 'mx'.  Then, we just create new columns on 'df' based on 'mx'.

```
lst <- strsplit(as.character(df$name), ",\\s*")
mx <- max(lengths(lst))
df[paste0("name", seq(mx))] <- lapply(lst, `length<-`, mx)
df[setdiff(names(df), "name")]
#  id grade name1 name2 name3
#1  1    12  rich chris larry
#2  2     9   tom  mary  <NA>
#3  3    10  todd  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  `name_3: Factor w/ 1 level "todd": 1 NA NA`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  Yes, because the previous case, the columns are returned as `factor` as the initial 'name' column, but in the `strsplit`, it will be `character` columns.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  I guess for the `factor`, the NA might be `NA_integer_`

Comment: works perfectly, thank you @akrun

Comment: for csplit (cSplit(df, "name", ",") can you split multiple columns with one line of code.  I tried several variations, but nothing worked for cSplit.  I tried something like this:  cSplit(df, "name", "subject", ",") but it didn't work.

Comment: @richiepop2  For that you need to concatenate i.e. `cSplit(df, c("name", "subject"), ",")`

Comment: ah, got it.  Thanks!!!